# Bind route and body values to same model on post request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

Is it possible to bind values from both the URL route and the body to the same model during a post request?

For example:

```
[Route("test")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("{valueFromRoute}/post")]
    public IActionResult Post(Model model)
    {
        return new JsonResult(model);
    }
}

public class Model
{
    [FromRoute]
    public string ValueFromRoute { get; set; }

    [FromBody]
    public string ValueFromBody { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to call this endpoint as follows:

[image]

However using this code, only the `ValueFromRoute` is populated:

```
{
    "valueFromRoute": "some-route-value",
    "valueFromBody": null
}
```

---

I'm guessing the answer is probably "no", and that two separate models would have to be used, such as:

```
[Route("test")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("{valueFromRoute}/post")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromRoute] RouteModel routeModel, [FromBody] BodyModel bodyModel)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new 
        { 
            ValueFromRoute = routeModel.ValueFromRoute, 
            ValueFromBody = bodyModel.ValueFromBody
        });
    }
}

public class RouteModel
{
    public string ValueFromRoute { get; set; }
}

public class BodyModel 
{
    public string ValueFromBody { get; set; }
}
```

Calling this in the exact same way as in the screenshot above works as expected, populating both values on their respective objects, and outputting the following:

```
{
    "valueFromRoute": "some-route-value",
    "valueFromBody": "Some value from body"
}
```

So I have a potential solution, but it's not my preferred solution. Ideally, I'd like to bind both route & body values to the same model, if possible.

Comment: Yeah. It's not possible. Each action param can only have one binding source.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt. I found that it actually *is* possible, and have posted the answer below if it's of interest to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this related question](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8111) on GitHub, which helped me understand that the body must be deserialised to a class object, even if it only contains one property, like my example above.

The solution to my example above is simply to create a new class for the body to be deserialised to, and add this to my main model expected by my action method.

```cs
[Route("test")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("{valueFromRoute}/post")]
    public IActionResult Post(Model model)
    {
        return new JsonResult(model);
    }
}

public class Model
{
    [FromRoute]
    public string ValueFromRoute { get; set; }
    
    // Map body to simple class object rather than a primitive type
    [FromBody]
    public BodyModel BodyModel { get; set; }
}

public class BodyModel 
{
    public string ValueFromBody { get; set; }
}
```

Additionally, if you want to map both your route parameters and body content to different objects, nested within the same object, this can be done as well:

```cs
[Route("test")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("{value1FromRoute}/{value2FromRoute}/post")]
    public IActionResult Post(Model model)
    {
        return new JsonResult(model);
    }
}

public class Model
{
    [FromBody]
    public BodyModel BodyModel { get; set; }

    [FromRoute, BindProperty(Name = "")]
    public RouteModel RouteModel { get; set; }
}

public class RouteModel
{
    public string Value1FromRoute { get; set; }
    public string Value2FromRoute { get; set; }
}

public class BodyModel
{
    public string ValueFromBody { get; set; }
}
```